# Drupal automaticly updates my custom source html content

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am writting an article on my Drupal 7 site directly with HTML source code.
When i save my content and want to modify it again, all my HTML source code has changed structure.

The display is what i want but the html source code is more complex then mine.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Ligne (collapse) -->
<a class="row ligne" data-toggle="collapse" href="#ligne-collapse-19">
  <!-- Titre ligne -->
  <div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12 titre-ligne">Transport en commun<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i></div>
  <!-- Contenu ligne -->
  <div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12">
    <div class="vals">
      <div class="col-xs-4"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></div>
      <div class="col-xs-4"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></div>
      <div class="col-xs-4"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
<!-- Contenu caché (collapse) -->
<div class="row collapse" id="ligne-collapse-19">
  <div class="ligne-detail">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-10 col-center">
      Profitez d'un mois gratuit* sur votre assurance auto pour toute nouvelle souscription.​
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Fin Ligne -->
```

Becomes

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col-md-5 col-xs-12 titre-ligne"><a class="row ligne" data-toggle="collapse" href="#ligne-collapse-1">Responsabilité civile<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></i></a></div>
<a class="row ligne" data-toggle="collapse" href="#ligne-collapse-1">
  <!-- Contenu ligne -->
</a>

<div class="col-md-7 col-xs-12">
  <div class="vals">
    <div class="col-xs-4"><a class="row ligne" data-toggle="collapse" href="#ligne-collapse-1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></a></div>

    <div class="col-xs-4"><a class="row ligne" data-toggle="collapse" href="#ligne-collapse-1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></a></div>

    <div class="col-xs-4"><a class="row ligne" data-toggle="collapse" href="#ligne-collapse-1"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></a></div>
  </div>
</div>
<a class="row ligne" data-toggle="collapse" href="#ligne-collapse-1"> </a>
<!-- Contenu caché (collapse) -->

<div class="row collapse" id="ligne-collapse-1">
  <div class="ligne-detail">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-xs-10 col-center">Elle couvre les dommages occasionnés par votre véhicule impliqué dans l'accident et constitue le minimum exigible de tout contrat d'assurance auto.</div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- Fin Ligne -->
```

All my links `<a href="..."` are splitted... what can i do to avoid this ?

Comment: Hi you don't talk about where did you setting this HTML if is a new template page or data come from an form admin setting page, this is a new module? or an overwriting core?

Comment: Using the text format "PHP" keeps Drupal from modifying my source code.

Comment: @headmax it's for an article body

Comment: if you want to change this outpout you need to create a new module and create you own display template for the article controller. https://www.digett.com/insights/change-output-single-field-drupal-7-node

Comment: if you want overwriting the core so you can do http://www.apaddedcell.com/change-html-output-drupal-7  but a warn cos this can broke update for the template using ...

Comment: You should definitely not be adding all that content into a single field. If you are, then you are using drupal wrong. For 1, jquery will already be loaded on the page by default. If you want to use bootstrap, look at using the [bootstrap theme](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap)

Comment: @2pha : I have a theme wich handles the js library for me (this was only for the example)

Comment: @headmax : overriding the core isn't a good idea, i will brake many features of core and other possible in plugins. I will look into digett.com. Thanks

Comment: @Loïc is the work you did, overriding the core on your example and i tell you on the top you have to create a new module and make a "HOOK" you module take the hand to display with your own template.

Comment: use <a name="TopBookmark"></a> for adding a bookmark. URL: http://smallbusiness.chron.com/make-bookmark-html-50150.html Your code will not work with href attribute

Answer (score 0):

As we can see in comments, there are no simple way to avoid Drupal from modifying custom HTML :

- With a module hook into the core (thanks @headmax)
- With Text format attribute put on "PHP Code"

I chose Text format because i have no time to spare on a new module.

Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the WYSIWYG module, there's a setting called "Apply simple source formatting" (at /admin/config/content/wysiwyg/) that will reformat your code, even if you are editing the source directly.

[image]

Comment: indeed, but i found out that we had CKEditor as WYSIWYG and i can't find that option. But thanks !